# What's the function of "reactive power diode" n3 and n4?

Tags: diodes, inverter, thyristor

[image]

I am trying to understand how the circuit above works. It is an inverter.
P1 and P2 are thyristors, they are fed with alternating pulses. What I have understood so far is that, Capacitor K4 is there to turn thyristors off (otherwise thyristors can't turn themselves off), Inductor K1 is there to smooth out excessive current because in brief moments, P1 and P2 may be conducting at the same time.

What I can not understand is why n3 and n4 is there. The documentation states:

> if the current has been flowing through section 3-1 of the primary winding and through thyristor P1 during the preceding half cycle, section 3-1 of the primary winding and diode n4 will carry the reactive current after commutating. This current is being driven by the inductive component of the load

I am guessing that K1 may at some instances drive point 5 or point 1 to negative voltage (let `Vdc-` be 0v). But my limited circuit knowledge can not handle this transient-heavy circuit.

If any kind person can simulate the circuit that would be nice, I would really like to see some wave forms around K1, K4 and the primary coils to gain better understanding of the circuit.

Comment: Could you please specify the signal between u and v and explain transformer (?) M1 a bit more?

Comment: Please check the cited text again: apart from typos, i think commuting should be commu**ta**ting

Comment: The values and phase of pulses are critical to get it working. Those diodes may be zeners.  Otherwise its a big DC short circuit

Answer (score 1):

The Center tapped Transformer M1 does have leakage Inductance   and Magnetising Inductance  .Current in the inductance means stored energy .A sharp fall in current like a fast turnoff  will make a voltage spike .Diodes n3 and n4 recover most of this inductive energy and clamp the pushpull center tapped primary winding EMF     to the B+ rail which has a low impedance at the switching frequency and its harmonics . The low impedance is usually realised with a large Bypass cap that has low reactance at the switching frequency,                                 Voltage spikes are a real problem on converters like this and the diodes are a cheap and simple way of reducing spikes.

Comment: [1] To reiterate: When P1 has conducted a while and P2's pulse just comes in. K4 robs all current from 3-1 sections of the primary winding, which I thought would have caused P1 to stop conducting.  However, you seem to suggest that primary winding is till releasing its stored energy, so K4 probably didn't rob all the the current going into P1, and according to your answer, P1 will be conducting for a while until the 3-1 primary is properly drained right? P1 and P2 will be conducting in parallel for quite a while (P1's current will be a ramp down instead of cut off)

Comment: [2] `clamp the pushpull center tapped primary winding to the B+ rail which has a low impedance at the switching frequency and its harmonics`. Sorry, I did not quite understand this sentence. I don't know what `B+` refers to. I don't understand the sentence in general. `clamp`, `pushpull primary winding`, `low impendance @ siwtching frequency`, `harmonics`. What should I google to get a grasp of those things?

Comment: [3] my understanding of n3 and n4 is that, they **alleviates** voltage spike problem by diverting some of the flows away from `Vdc-` and back into the primary coil 3-5. Is that correct? (in the real circuit, n3 and n4 doesn't go into point 3 and 5, it actually goes into mid points of coil 3-1 and 3-5)